# SAS rand("Normal") generates strange distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, bootstrap, simulation, sas

I'm attempting a parametric bootstrap of a statistic in SAS. I'm using the RAND("Normal") function to generate a distribution around the statistic similar to this: 
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/SAS1387-2015.pdf.

XRate is actually more complicated with an unknown variance (hence the bootstrap), but let's say I do this 25,000 times...

xrate = rate + std * rand("Normal");

I create the original rates from a large dataset within subpopulations, and overall. The within-subpopulation bootstrapped estimates look ok. A little skewed sometimes, but mostly Normal. The overall rate, however, which goes through the same process as the within-subpopulation rates, looks like this. Not sure what to call the little humps on either end of the main distribution, nor can I fathom where they are coming from. Why is it doing this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

[image: Histogram of XRate]

EDIT: More details...
XRate is the average difference between a minimum percent (+/- a random deviation) and 1 to 4 other percentages (+/- a random deviation). This is done several thousand times. The distribution of XRate for all the subpopulation estimates look ok, but the overall estimates (which have a much larger sample) result in a distribution posted above.

The rates are rounded because this process was producing estimates with means that did not match the actual point estimate (which is rounded) for which I'm trying to generate confidence intervals.

Within a macro that cycles through the different combinations of rates...

```
data outboot;
array rate [&ratecnt] rate_1 - rate_&ratecnt (&pRATE);
array stde [&ratecnt] stde_1 - stde_&ratecnt (&STDERR);

min_pos = WHICHN(MIN(OF rate{*}),OF rate{*});

call streaminit(4511);

do Replicate = 1 to 25000;
min_rate = rate{min_pos}/100 + stde{min_pos} * rand("Normal");
    %DO j=1 %TO &ratecnt;
        IF min_pos = &j then x&j = .;
        ELSE x&j = 100*((ROUND(rate{&j},0.1)/100 + stde{&j} * rand("Normal")) - ROUND(min_rate,0.001))/ROUND(min_rate,0.001);
        %END;
    XRate = MEAN(OF x1 - x%EVAL(&j-1));

    output;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: It's not sufficiently clear what you did. Please describe in detail. (It's possible that your post may end up off topic here depending on whether it ends up being a statistical problem or a programming problem but either way more details will be needed.)

Comment: I edited the original post, but it still says it is on hold. Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: You edited a little over an hour ago. The edit places it in a review queue for our high-reputation users to check (to see if they think it's reasonably clear). Even if every reviewer thinks so, that can take some time. At this time many people are asleep; others in other locations may be eating or working or any of the other things that people spend time on. It might take a few hours. It hit the review queue about 45 minutes ago; if it's not open in about 16-18 hours, you may need to look at improving it further.

Comment: It looks like a mixture of (at least) three normals. I do not understand your code but does that give you a clue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by rounding the rates during the calculation.

Comment: If you want to present this as the answer to your question, you can accept this by clicking the check mark to its left beneath the vote total. You might want to expand it a little, though.